# I don't want the form to be drawn progressively from top to down. I want it to be displayed all at once

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a Windows form in which I add a number of LinkLabels in my c# code. 
The problem I have is that when the form is displayed, it is drown on the screen progressively from top to down. But I want it to appear suddenly and fast. What should I do?
I even tried this but didn't help:
I set the visible to false. Then filled out the form with all the labels. Then called the show.

(I new() and show() my form in a MouseEnter event of a label in another form.)

Edit:I also have tried the DoubleBuffer. Didn't help.
I should note that I don't care if the whole form appears with a delay. I just want it to appear all at once. Because in my case a little delay is inevitable. Cause the data is retrieved from the network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using `DoubleBuffered = true`?

Answer (score 4):

As a guess try setting `DoubleBuffered = true` on the form. This is supposed to render the entire form surface to a memory buffer before drawing it on the screen. However, a better solution is to find out what is causing your form to render so slowly. Forms are usually imperceptible unless there is a lot of logic happening in the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

You need to profile your applicaiton, some possible reasons for that could be:

- intensive data population during loading (can be reduced by quantity of controls need to be visualized, quantity of data to load or run in another thread)
- too much controls on view (just organize them in different TabPages of TabControl. *If* there are too much controls, avoid them, cause no any user will be need them all contemporary.
- Last and not least: is `SuspendLayout`()/`ResumeLayout`() in the biegining of loading and at the end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess my problem was that I had retrieved the data in the constructor rather than in the Load(). I moved it from the constructor tho the load() and I also reduced the number of controls according to your advice. It is much better now. Thank you for the fast help :) .

Comment: You need to profile your application in order to identify a bottlenecks. I just give a list of possible, most common fails we do that can cause the problem you have. Can use free performance [Eqated](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/)  profiler to measure it.

Comment: @seff: This is just concept, not related to VS or ctor, but Loading like a procedure. If berfore showing something you need to laod a data (say) from DataBase, bind it to all controls it will cost time. That is. And *if* you do it during the load of the form, the final rendering-apperance of it will be delayed naturally.

Comment: Sorry Tigran I was wrong. I thought the problem was almost solved because I had reduced the number of my LinkLabels to 30. Now I increased it to 90 LinkLabels and the problem still exists :( I have to Display 30 lines of LinkLabels and in each row I have 3 of them.

Comment: @so try to apply other listed techniques, but first *measure* with profiler. It's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

Perhaps put all of your `LinkLabel`s on a `Panel`, set the `Panel`'s `Dock` to `Fill`, and then add the `Panel` to the `Form`.